# Duplicate entry 'KEY' for 'PRIMARY' using MySQL

Tags: sql, linux, terminal, mariadb

I followed this short guide to install cacti using mysql and other tools:
https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/how-to-install-cacti-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-bionic-beaver.html

In this section:

> To do that, import the mysql_test_data_timezone.sql to mysql database.
>
> `mysql -u root -p mysql < /usr/share/mysql/mysql_test_data_timezone.sql`

I accidentally copied this command, not one but two times: `mysql -u root -p mysql < /usr/share/mysql/mysql_test_data_timezone.sql`

The prompt said:

```
ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 17: Duplicate entry 'MET' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Does this mean that I have to remove duplicates before doing anything else with mysql ? How do I search for the duplicate ?

Comment: You aren't allowed to have duplicate names in the primary fields. The data won't be inputted. So you don't need to remove it. But better check it again for no duplicates.

Comment: @TimothyLukasH. - That script has `INSERT` statements.  The OP said he ran it twice.  So, clearly, it is likely to get dups.

Comment: @RickJames It depends on the SQL statements and how they are executed. If they all depend on the duplicate key, it won't get any dups. If there are other statements, there will be.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is no harm.

That command loads some information into some timezone tables in the database.  The error occurred because of trying to load the same data a second time.  Assuming it totally failed, then there is no harm.